# Obout controls (grid,textbox,calendar) problems

Tags: textbox, calendar, grid, obout

I have problem with Obout calendar and textbox inside obout grid edit template.

This is the code of my grid :

```
 <obout2:Grid ID="grid1" runat="server" CallbackMode="false" Serialize="true"
         ShowHeader="true" PageSize="10"
        FolderStyle="~/styles/Grid/black_glass" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableRecordHover="true"
        AllowAddingRecords="true" RowEditTemplateId="tplRowEdit">
        <Columns>
            <obout2:Column ID="Column1" DataField="ID_Nal" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" HeaderText="ID_Nal"
                Width="100" runat="server">
                <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtID_Nal" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
            </obout2:Column>
            <obout2:Column ID="Column2" DataField="ID_Wpl" Visible="false" HeaderText="ID_Wpl"
                Width="200" runat="server">
                <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtID_Wpl" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
            </obout2:Column>
            <obout2:Column ID="Column3" DataField="Nazwa" HeaderText="Typ_Naleznosci" Width="150"
                runat="server">
                <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtTyp" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
            </obout2:Column>
            <obout2:Column ID="Column4" DataField="KwotaN" HeaderText="Kwota Nalezności" Width="150"
                runat="server">
                <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtKwotaN" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
            </obout2:Column>
            <obout2:Column ID="Column5" DataField="Termin_platnosci" HeaderText="Termin_platnosci"
                Width="150" runat="server">
                <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtTermin" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
            </obout2:Column>
            <obout2:Column ID="Column7" DataField="Opis" HeaderText="Opis nal." Width="150" runat="server">
                <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtOpis" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
            </obout2:Column>
            <obout2:Column ID="Column8" DataField="KwotaW" HeaderText="Kwota wpłaty" Width="150"
                runat="server">
                <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtKwotaW" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
            </obout2:Column>
            <obout2:Column ID="Column9" DataField="DataW" HeaderText="Data wpłaty" Width="150"
                runat="server">
                <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtDataW" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
            </obout2:Column>
            <obout2:Column ID="Column10" DataField="OpisW" HeaderText="Opis wpłaty" Width="150"
                runat="server">
                <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtOpisW" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value" />
            </obout2:Column>
            <obout2:Column ID="Column11" HeaderText="" Width="200" AllowEdit="true" Align="center"
                AllowDelete="true" runat="server" />
        </Columns>
        <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateId="tplRowEdit" />
        <Templates>
            <obout2:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="tplRowEdit">
                <Template>
                    <div style="position: relative;">
                        <table class="rowEditTable">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top">
                                    <fieldset style="width: 275px; height: 250px;">
                                        <legend>Ship Information</legend>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="120">
                                                    ID Nal:
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <obout1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="txtID_Nal" Width="150" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="120">
                                                    Id Wpl:
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <obout1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="txtID_Wpl" Width="150" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="120">
                                                    Typ:
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <obout1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="txtTyp" Width="150" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="120">
                                                    Kwota:
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <obout1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="txtKwotaN" Width="150" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="120">
                                                    Termin płatności:
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <obout1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="txtTermin" Width="150" />

                                                </td>
                                               <td>
                                                    <obout:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" DatePickerMode="true" DatePickerImagePath="~/Styles/Calendar/icon2.gif"
                                                        StyleFolder="~/Styles/Calendar/default"
                                                        TextBoxId="txtTermin" CultureName="pl-PL" DateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy">
                                                    </obout:Calendar>
                                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="120">
                                        Opis:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <obout1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="txtOpis" Width="150" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="120">
                                        Kwota wpłaty:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <obout1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="txtKwotaW" Width="150" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="120">
                                        Data wpłaty:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <obout1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="txtDataW" Width="150" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <obout:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" DatePickerMode="true" DatePickerImagePath="~/Styles/Calendar/icon2.gif"
                                            StyleFolder="~/Styles/Calendar/default" CultureName="pl-PL" DateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
                                            ShowHourSelector="False" ShowMinuteSelector="False" ShowSecondSelector="False"
                                            TextBoxId="txtDataW">
                                        </obout:Calendar>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="120">
                                        Opis wpłaty:
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <obout1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="txtOpisW" Width="150" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <br />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table> </fieldset> </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                    <obout1:OboutButton ID="BtnSaveChanges" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return saveChanges('BtnSaveChanges')" />
                                    <obout1:OboutButton ID="BtnCancelChanges" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClientClick="return cancelChanges('BtnCancelChanges');" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div class="loading-image-container" id="LoadingIndicator" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="loading-image">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Template>
            </obout2:GridTemplate>
        </Templates>
    </obout2:Grid>
```

When i run the code and click the calendar near "txtTermin" the calendar is displayed,but when i change the date in calendar it was not changed in textbox (txtTermin).

But when I replace

```
<obout1:OboutTextBox runat="server" ID="txtTermin" Width="150" />
```

with

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTermin" Width="150" />
```

everything is working OK.

Of course the same problem is with txtDataW.

Please help, why calendar doesn't work with OboutTextBox,but works with standard ASP TextBox  ? In this example : http://www.obout.com/grid/grid_commands_row_template.aspx it works (Order Date,Required Date..) with OboutTextBox'es.